# Query work items of previous iteration in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to query VSTS work items which are assigned to the previous iteration, i.e. `@CurrentIteration - 1`.

I can use hardcoded `Iteration path` values, but then I'd need to update my queries every sprint.

Is there a way to automatize it?

**update**

It's added now, see [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/release-notes/2018/mar-05-vsts#query-work-across-the-iteration-schedule-with---currentiteration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any way to achieve this for now. And there is already a feature request submitted on VSTS User Voice, check and vote it here: [VSO Support @currentIteration+-1 for next or past iteration](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13314216-vso-support-currentiteration-1-for-next-or-past).